# Library for Polygon vertex reduction keeping almost the same shape

Tags: c++, polygon

I'm using the c++ version of the polygon clipping library [Clipper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/polyclipping/) and I would like to reduce the number of vertex in my polygons, keeping almost the same shapes.

As additional requirement I have to approximate my polygons "outwards only": the resulting simplified polygon must cointains the original one.

I thought about:

- convex hull, which satisfies the "outward only" condition, but it simplify my polygons too much
- the [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm), which is good since it let me choose the error but it does not satisfy the "outward only" condition.

Then I gave a look at [psimpl library](http://psimpl.sourceforge.net), and the most close algorithm to my requirements seemed to be the [Opheneim algorithm](http://psimpl.sourceforge.net/opheim.html) which

> uses both a minimum and a maximum distance tolerance to constrain the search area

but the minimum distance cannot be 0.

Is there any possible solution to this problem? Do you know any c++ library which solves it?

Comment: not that I reccommend to use VTK only for that purpose, you may want to have a look into the vtkDecimatePro class to find clues on how they do it. They also quite well documented what they do with the data when: http://www.vtk.org/doc/release/4.0/html/classvtkDecimatePro.html#_details

Comment: 2D or 3D? If 3D, `mesh decimation` is the Google term. E.g. - http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.0-Documentation/decimater_docu.html

Comment: @roger_rowland 2D, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to iterate around polygon and do:

1. If the vertex is concave and distance to line, connecting neighbour vertices < `tolerance`, than remove it.
2. If the vertex is convex, consider previous segemnt lies on line `L1`, iterate further, while `L1` intersects line, containing next segment, in point `P` outside polygon and distance from `P` to polygon < `tolerance`, and distance the beginning of segment to `L1` < `tolerance`. When that iteration stops (not on the first iteration), remove intermediate points, insert intersection point(previous if current is inside polygon and current if it is on border).

Keep iterating polygon, while simplification happens. Also be sure to keep somwhere old points to check tolerance(for example you could enumerate vertices, and remove indices while simplifying, but when checking tolerance, check intermediate indices too)

It is not super-fast algorithm, but does what you want.

[image: Examples]

Comment: Since I would use this simplification just once, before some other computation, speed doesn't matter. I will try. Thank you.